# Room Database. Insert sucessfull but no data found

Tags: java, android, sqlite, observable, android-room

I've got a simple Room database setup as seen below:

Entity Class

```
@Entity
public class User {
 @PrimaryKey
 public int uid;

 @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
 public String firstName;

 @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
 public String lastName;

 public User(int uid, String firstName, String lastName){
     this.uid = uid;
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
 }
}
```

My Dao Interface:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

 @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
 Flowable<List<User>> getAlls();

 @Insert
 Completable addData(User modelClass);
}
```

My Database:

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

 private static AppDatabase instance;

 static AppDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {
     if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "your_db_name").createFromFile(new File("mypath")).build();
     }
     return instance;
 }

 public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

Finally my ViewModel:

```
public class RoomWithRxJavaViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

 private AppDatabase appDatabase;

 public RoomWithRxJavaViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
 }

 public Flowable<List<User>> getList() {
    return appDatabase.userDao().getAlls().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
 }

 public Completable addData(User modelClass) {

     return Completable.fromAction(() -> appDatabase.userDao().addData(modelClass))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
 }

}
```

And my Activity where I print the results:

```
RoomWithRxJavaViewModel viewModel = new RoomWithRxJavaViewModel(this.getApplication());

Disposable disposable = viewModel.addData(new User(2, "btt", "bbb"))
.subscribe(
 () -> { //onSucess
   Toast.makeText(this, "Completed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Disposable subscribe = viewModel.getList()
   .subscribe(modelClasses ->
       {
         Toast.makeText(this, "RoomWithRx: " + modelClasses.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }, e -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
}, //onError
   throwable -> {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Error!" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
);
```

As you can see from the code, I first try creating a default user in my database.

If the insert is sucessfull, which it is cause I always enter the onSucess function, i want to check the size of the updated User Table and here's the catch:
No matter how often I insert the user using the code, the size is remains always 0.

Am I missing something?

Comment: are you observing size = 0 when running unit tests?

Comment: @Southstar no, would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, tests are transactional - they create and when finished they delete the row

Comment: @Southstar but i dont run a unit test. I test it locally on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAO:

```
@Insert
Single<Long> insert(User user);
```

Change Completable to Single as following:

```
public Single<Long> addData2(User user) {
    return appDatabase.userDao().addData(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

And your modelview should look like this:

```
Disposable subscribe1 = viewModel.addData2(new User(4, "some", "user"))
 .subscribe(
  id -> { //onSucess },
  throwable -> { //onerror }
);
```